# Silverlight 4 : Update Data in DataBase

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am looking for some Sliverlight 4 Application/ example that uses **MVVM** pattern to update data Back in Data-Base also.

so that I can follow that approach for Developing Silverlight  Application.

any External Link will work.

Comment: Where is the database? How are you accessing it? WCF Services? Something else?

Comment: @Nate , currently  Linq-SQL.
  but , will the approach change if Source of Data is Different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight can't use Linq-To-Sql because it cannot connect directly to a database. Here is a good tutorial on getting up to speed with Silverlight and MVVM.

//EDIT -- You cannot use L2Sql directly from Silverlight. You'd have to call a WCF service to create an action on the server side that could then use Linq to Sql to read/write to/from the db.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse.aspx